# Spring Security not working properly

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, http-status-code-403

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/entrysheet/**").permitAll()//.hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN") //Needs to be first
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    ;
}


@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UsersRepository usersRepository;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    System.out.println("fdsfdsfsd");
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    usersRepository.findAll().forEach(users -> {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername(users.getUsername()).password(users.getPassword())
                .roles((users.getIdRole() != null && users.getIdRole() == 1) ? "ADMIN" : "USER").build();
        System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername() + " " + userDetails.getPassword() +
                userDetails.getAuthorities());

        manager.createUser(userDetails);
            }
    );

    return manager;
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
           //.antMatchers("/entrysheet/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()//.hasRole("USER")
           //.antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN") //Needs to be first
            .antMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll() //Permit all other roles to all other paths
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            //.authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/entrysheet/**").permitAll()//.hasRole("USER")
            //.antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN") //Needs to be first
            //.anyRequest().authenticated()


    ;
}
```

}

Here is my configuration. But seems that /users/ can not be accessed by anyone.

Whenever I put a ".hasRole("RoleName")" it will just deny access for that role. I get a 
    {
    "timestamp": 1526671066818,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/users"
}

from that.

What I want is that some requests are allowed only to "USER" for example: "/entrysheet", "/datasheet", etc. while only "/users" accessible by "ADMIN"

Comment: *But seems that /users/ can not be accessed by anyone.* Sure, you configured `.antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`, hence only users with role `ADMIN` can access the URL.

Comment: @dur it is not accessed by ADMIN too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be carefull between both

```
 hasRole([role])
```

> Returns true if the current principal has the specified role. By
>   default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be
>   added. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on
>   DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

or

```
hasAuthority([authority])
```

> Returns true if the current principal has the specified authority

the first one will add by default "ROLE_" to the value specified

So i would change to `hasAuthority`

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html)